# Jetbrains Rider, how to disable text indenting within documentation comments (summary tags)?

Tags: rider

In Jetbrains Rider 2021.3x, after executing `Code Clean Up`, text in [documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags) are being indented. How can this be disabled? In the example below, rider inserts the text indents in the summary tag, want to prevent this:

```
   /// <summary>
   ///    Why does Rider indent these comments? How can it be disabled?
   ///    Any idea of what settings!?
   /// </summary>
   public class Person{}
```

After Code Cleanup execution, the text should have no indents, like below:

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Why does Rider indent these comments? How can it be disabled?
   /// Any idea of what settings!?
   /// </summary>
   public class Person{}
```

Just struggling to find the correct settings...

Answer (score 5):

Go to *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C#* and open the tab *XML documentation*. There you should find the setting *Indent inside element that contain text* which you can set to *No indent from parent element*:
[image]

Comment: If this suffices your needs, please consider accepting it as an answer so that the question gets closed :)